# Libflycapture.so: undefined reference to ‘powf@GLIBC_2.27’

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, my system info: x86_64, Ubuntu 16.04.6, kernel 4.15.0-54-generic,  gcc5.4.0, g++5.4.0,
autoware-1.11.1.

Installed [flycapture2-2.13.3.31-amd64-pkg_xenial](https://flir.app.boxcn.net/v/Flycapture2SDK),  [LaydbugSDK_1.16.3.48_amd64](https://flir.app.boxcn.net/v/LadybugSDK/folder/72272663556) and  [spinnaker-1.21.0.61-amd64-Ubuntu16.04](https://flir.app.boxcn.net/v/SpinnakerSDK/folder/74727114471), then reboot to build autoware. when building with `AUTOWARE_COMPILE_WITH_CUDA=1 ./colcon_release`, output:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libflycapture.so： undefined reference to  ‘powf@GLIBC_2.27’
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [devel/lib/autoware_pointgrey_drivers/grasshopper3_camera] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/grasshopper3_camera.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished tasks....
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libladybug.so： undefined reference to ‘FlyCapture2::AVIRecorder::AVIRecorder()’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libflycapture.so： undefined reference to ‘powf@GLIBC_2.27’
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [devel/lib/autoware_pointgrey_drivers/ladybug_camera] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ladybug_camera.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
 ---
Failed   <<< autoware_pointgrey_drivers [ Exited with code 2 ]
```

In `Autoware/ros/src/sensing/drivers/camera/packages/pointgrey`, the README file doesn't specify the three matched SDK(flycapture, ladybug, spinnaker) version. How to fix this this problem? Did i missing something, thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327482/libflycapture.so:-undefined-reference-to-%E2%80%98powf@glibc_2.27%E2%80%99/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2019-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@jxl
There are two problem I can see here:

**1. I suspect your system is not Ubuntu 16.04, but 18.04. (glibc version)**

The highest glibc version available in Ubuntu 16.04 (as of July 2019) is [2.23](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/glibc), but the linker is stating your version is [2.27](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/glibc), which suspiciously corresponds to the one shipped in Ubuntu 18.04.

You might confirm your glib version executing:
`ldd --version`

and your Ubuntu version executing:
 `lsb_release -a`

If you happen to be on Ubuntu 18.04, you'll need to remove previous `xenial` version, download and install the `bionic` version of the [driver](https://flir.app.boxcn.net/v/Flycapture2SDK/file/434084765399).

**2. `libladybug.so： undefined reference to ‘FlyCapture2::AVIRecorder::AVIRecorder()’`**

You cannot install standard FlyCapture SDK (for grashoppers, cameleon cameras, etc)  simultaneously with Ladybug's FlyCapture.

---

Originally posted by [amc-nu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41091/amc-nu/) with karma: 136 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2019-07-09**:
@amc-nu Thanks for your time and guide very much, i will have a try. `jxl@dell:~$ ldd --version ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu11) 2.23 Copyright (C) 2016 自由软件基金会。 jxl@dell:~$ lsb_release -a No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS Release:    16.04 Codename:   xenial jxl@dell:~$`  .

**Comment by [amc-nu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41091/amc-nu/) on 2019-07-09**:
Then it's the other way around,  you have installed the `bionic` version of the FlyCapture SDK. which is expecting glib 2.27.